# How to write a simple extension with variable arguments?

Tags: python, jinja2, template-engine

I would like to implement a custom extension with [jinja2](/questions/tagged/jinja2) that allow dynamical loading of an external datasource. For example:

```
{# A jinja template #}
{% datasource '../foo.yml' %}

{{ foo }}
{{ bar }}
```

So I wrote this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from jinja2 import Template, nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class Test(Extension):
    tags = set(['datasource'])

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno
        args = [parser.parse_expression()]
        call = self.call_method('_render', args)
        return nodes.Output([call], lineno=lineno)

    def _render(self, name):
        print name
        print "Hello from render"
        return None

x = """
{# A jinja template #}
{% datasource '../foo.yml' %}

{{ foo }}
{{ bar }}
"""

t = Template(x, extensions=[Test])
t.render()
```

It works well if I use:

```
{% datasource '../foo.yml' %}
```

However if I miss the argument `'../foo.yml'`, I get a long traceback that is hard to understand:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected 'end of statement block'
```

If I add a second argument, I also get an error:

```
{% datasource 'foo', 'bar' %}

TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got ','
```

How should I implement that?

Bonus question: is `lineno=lineno` necessary?